Breaking a face with multiple triangles into component triangles
My mesh has three triangles that are in a weird relationship. The "middle" triangle is its own face, while attempting to select either of the "outer" two triangles as a face ends up selecting all three triangles as a single face. How can I break the macro triangle into separate faces? (I need to select just the bottom triangle for some manipulation.)

middle triangle selected

selecting left or bottom triangle is a single macro face

Is it possible that the large triangle is actually it's own five-sided polygon? In that case it should be easier to just delete it (x -> delete faces) and fill the remaining two triangles manually.

Yeah, I second this, you have a smaller triangle overlapping a larger triangle making it look like 3. Delete the "macro" face and refill the remainder.

@LuigiTKO Thank you for the advice. That worked. If you care to write this as an answer, I'll accept it.

The larger triangle you're seeing is actually a five-sided polygon, which overlaps with the middle triangle causing the illusion of three triangles.


You can fix this by deleting the larger triangle (x -> delete faces) and filling the resulting holes with the F key.


